# When generate build an error comes, "export 'ɵba' (imported as 'i10') was not found in '@angular/forms'

Tags: runtime-error, angular5, angular-forms, updating, angular8

After upgrade angular version 5-8, I have facing an error and some module is not working. and when generate build is is through an error.

**I am trying to update all library @latest.**

Need to generate build properly without below error. I am stuck here.

**("export 'ɵba' (imported as 'i10') was not found in '@angular/forms')**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I find out the issue.
 The issue is in an ngx-select-dropdown library. when I upgrade angular version then the ngx-select-dropdown library, not support and nothing give any error related to the library.

I try to remove one by one library from my module then I found the issue is on this library.

Now my issue resolved after removing the ngx-select-dropdown library.

Comment: how did you find that library?